# Issue in playing Pre-roll ads in Jwplayer 6 Html5-video tag

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html5-video, jwplayer6

I am using Jwplayer 6 Ad version for both flash as well as html5 player where
flash player is working fine as well as pre-roll ads are coming but IOS/Android devices support Html5 player where pre-roll ads are displaying.

**Player Configuration Support Link**: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/22644/using-the-html5-video-tag/

**Issue**: Pre-roll ads are not coming while playing videos on various IOS/Andriod devices in html5 player.

```
<script src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
  <div id='vidShow' style='text-align:center'></div>
  <video height='388' width='658' id='vidShow' autoplay autobuffer controls>
  <source src='$videoURL' type='video/mp4'></video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer.key='ZntNkhG6CqNXBkJnV4sYqVjYopC38oGcp0GjCQ==';
jwplayer('vidShow').setup({
  modes: [
  { type: 'html5' },
  { type: 'flash', src: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf' },
    advertising: {
    client: 'vast',
    schedule: {
    myPreroll:
    {
    offset: 'pre',
    tag: 'http://xp1.zedo.com/jsc/c2/fns.vast?n=2135__amp__c=121/102__amp__d=22__amp__s=1__amp__v=vast2__amp__pu=__page-url____amp__ru=__referrer____amp__pw=__player-width____amp__ph=__player-height____amp__z=__random-number__'
    }}}]
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use... JW PLAYER v6.8+ (Working)

```
<div id="mediabox_video" style="width:100%; height:100%;">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediabox_video").setup({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        autostart: true,
        playlist: [{
            sources: [
                {bitrate: "360", file: "http://110.164.180.149/video39/1930daa7bced9bcbfb8131af6e8a34fb/5320014b/2014/03/11/1394544732/1394544732_360.mp4", label: "360p", type: "video/mp4", provider: "video"},
                {bitrate: "480", file: "http://110.164.180.149/video39/bf9b55c3f9c3b71291e3c09aff6ba4ae/5320014b/2014/03/11/1394544732/1394544732_480.mp4", label: "480p", type: "video/mp4", provider: "video"},
            ]
        }],
        advertising: {
            client: "vast",
            schedule: {
                adbreak1: {
                    offset: 'pre',
                    tag: 'http://xp1.zedo.com/jsc/c2/fns.vast?n=2135__amp__c=121/102__amp__d=22__amp__s=1__amp__v=vast2__amp__pu=__page-url____amp__ru=__referrer____amp__pw=__player-width____amp__ph=__player-height____amp__z=__random-number__'
                }
             }
        }   
    });
</script>
```